# How Do I Center The Input Fields On This Form?

Tags: forms

https://ibb.co/3M8TjjY

**Codepen**

https://codepen.io/shon-lucky/pen/WNozGRe?editors=1100

Trying to center this form and its beating me up. So far i have used margin: auto. But everytime i do the form centers but the input elements are not centered in the form. I have used positioning where i made the parent container relative and made the form absolute but the everything dissapears before i even try to move it. Can someone help me with this plz

```
<form action="">
    
    <div class="firstrow">
    <label for="How Many People">How Many People</label>
    <input type="text">
   </div>

   <div class="firstrow">
   <label for="date">Date</label>
   <input type="text">
   </div>

   <div class="firstrow">
    <label for="time">Time</label>
    <input type="text">
    </div>

   <br style="clear:both">

   <div class="secondrow">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your full name">
   </div>

   <div class="secondrow">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input type="text">
   </div>

   <div class="secondrow">
    <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="You phone">
    </div>
  </div>
   </form>
   
</section>

.section4{
  width:100%;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: #374a5c;

}

.section4 .wrapper{
  width:80%;
  height:380px;
  margin:auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
}

form{

}



label,input{
  display:block;
    }



.firstrow{
  float: left;
}

.secondrow{
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Could you create a codepen from https://codepen.io/ and share the link with the whole page so that we can give you a proper solution ? thanks :-)

Comment: https://codepen.io/shon-lucky/pen/WNozGRe?editors=1100

Comment: here is the codepen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the Codepen! Here is a fix to center the form elements:
[image]

Link to the edited pen : https://codepen.io/pathiout/pen/YzpaLdR?editors=1100

Here is the css I used :

```
.firstrow {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.secondrow {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Basically I removed the "float left" attributes that prevents any centering from parent. Is this an acceptable solution for you ?

Comment: Thank you. Can you center any inline block with text align?

Comment: Yes inline-blocks can be centered with text-align:center in parent :) If this solution is acceptable to you please approve it :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried text-align? Sometimes in HTML, the text align can center html element other than text, I've used it many times already.

```
<div style="text-align: center"><input type="text"> ....
```

Comment: first thing i tried was text align and then i tried margin: auto with the width defined